# how to read current value in sql

Tags: php, mysql, search, select, count

i created a search function :

```
SELECT
    tbl_place.id AS id, 
    tbl_place.metalink AS metalink, 
    tbl_place.title AS title, 
    tbl_place.img_thumbnail AS img_thumbnail, 
    tbl_place.category1_id AS category1_id, 
    tbl_place.category2_id AS category2_id, 
    tbl_place.category3_id AS category3_id, 
    tbl_place.region_id AS region_id, 
    tbl_place.subregion_id AS subregion_id, 
    tbl_place.summary AS summary, 
    (SELECT COUNT(tbl_place.title) FROM tbl_place) AS total_show_up
FROM tbl_place 
WHERE 
    tbl_place.title LIKE '%$keywords[0]%' AND
    tbl_place.title LIKE '%$keywords[1]%'
```

if i search with keywords: "Pizza Store", it will display something like this:

```
* Pizza Store
* Pizza Store Manhattan
* Pizza Store California
* Pizza Store California
* Pizza Store Texas
* Pizza Store California
```

And what i want to do is, also count how many times each tbl_place.title show up while the query is still searching with the keywords.
I want the result to become like this:

```
* Pizza Store - showed 1 time
* Pizza Store Manhattan - showed 1 time
* Pizza Store California - showed 3 times
* Pizza Store California - showed 3 times
* Pizza Store Texas - showed 1 time
* Pizza Store California - showed 3 times
```

Is there any syntax to read current value of tbl_place while SELECT-ing?

I believe i change something in this part of the query :

```
(SELECT COUNT(tbl_place.title) FROM tbl_place) AS total_show_up
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here? How to display the data?

Comment: You should use COUNT(tbl_place.title) AS total_show_up instead of your (select count(tbl_place.title) FROM ...)

Comment: @JanHančič : i want to display total_show_up also

Comment: @GuZzie : if i use  COUNT(tbl_place.title) AS total_show_up it will return all the rows, but what i want is when the query is start to select a row per row, it also search the current title in the whole table AS total_show_up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an approach like this:

```
SELECT
   p1.title, pj.total
FROM 
   pizza p1
JOIN 
   (
    SELECT 
       p2.title title, COUNT(p2.id) total
    FROM pizza p2 
    WHERE p2.title LIKE '%Pizza%' AND p2.title LIKE '%Store%'
    GROUP BY p2.title
   ) AS pj
ON p1.title=pj.title
```

Comment: i believe your query is similar with GuZzie

Comment: There is no JOIN on GuZzie query

Comment: what i want to do is, also count how many times each tbl_place.title show up while the query is still searching with the keyword. Not the total rows of keyword.

Comment: What do you mean with "total rows of keyword"? The query that I've written gives exactly the output that you want. What is the problem with this approach?

Comment: What i mean with total rows of keyword is when user search "Pizza Store" it will return total search result, say it 180 rows. What i want is for each title that match with "Pizza Store" will be counted also as each total_show_up, lets say like: "Pizza Store Manhattan" -showed for 1 time, "Pizza  Store California" - showed for 3 times

Comment: Perhaps can i add something like this in my query? (SELECT COUNT(tbl_place.title) FROM tbl_place WHERE tbl_place.title = title) AS total_show_up

this "title" is what i SELECT before AS 'title'.

Comment: hey, btw i have found the query. thx for u jordeu! for giving me table alias inspiration!